# How to use a function output as a input for another function

Tags: python

In the example below i would like to use the output from fun1 in fun2. I get an error stating x is not defined. This is something extremely simple but i just don't get it.

```
def fun1():
    x = input('put here the value')
    return x

fun1()

def fun2(x):
  y = x + 2
  print(y)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can assign it into a variable

```
x = fun1()
fun2(x)
```

Or just directly pass the result into the next function

```
fun2(fun1())
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you also added an explanation regarding *why* the OP's attempt is failing (scope and not storing variables). I'd add an answer myself explaining that but seeing as this answer is already so popular it's unlikely I'd get any upvotes or be seen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was quite helpful. What if the first function return 3 strings ( 'a', 'b', 'c'). I am trying to use those variables as an input for the second function.

Comment: first you would capture them, like `x, y ,z = fun1() ` then pass them as a parms of `fun2`.

Answer (score 1):

From your own code:

```
def fun1():
    x = input('put here the value')
    return x

x = fun1()

def fun2(x):
  y = x + 2
  print(y)

fun2(x)
```

Or you could take another approach, by calling the `fun1()` from `fun2` and removing the param x.